# Connecting Azure account from PowerShell is not happening due to error in description

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Connecting Azure account from PowerShell is not happening due to error in description.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-AzAccount
WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant '36ff3f25-cbe8-48b8-ba26-58974869160e'
WARNING: Unable to set default context 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureContext'.
Connect-AzAccount : Run Connect-AzAccount to login.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: @JasonPan , Hi there, I'm facing the same issue, whereby am accessing azure account,for the first time! Should also delete the account,i have just used to register/login

Answer (score 0):

If it runs normally before, it is recommended to manually delete the two files `AzureRMContext.json` and `AzureRmContextSettings.json`. You can find them in the `C:\Users\Administrator\.azure\` folder.  Or run command `Clear-AzContext`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the simliar error messenger

> Connect-AzAccount -environment AzureChinaCloud

```
WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' with error 'SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No account matching the specified username: aaaaa@email.com tenantId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx was found in the cache.'
WARNING: Unable to set default context 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureContext'
```

Jason's reply give me tips.  I have clean the cache file and it makes it work.

here is I did

1. Go to C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local.IdentityService, delete "msal.cache"
2. go to C:\Users<username>.Azure, delete 4 files "azureProfile.json", "azureRmcontext.json", "azureRmsurvey.json", and "clouds.config"
3. Close VSCode and relanch VSCode.

Now, VScode terminal log me in.

Hope it can help.